# Resources and requirements for amateur spectroscopy

Tags: astronomy, spectroscopy

If I wanted to move beyond just looking through my eyepieces and taking photographs of astronomical objects, what can I do do move into astronomical spectroscopy?

Are there any good resources for this?  Pitfalls?  And perhaps most importantly, what kind of initial outlay would I have to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's surprisingly easy and inexpensive to do astronomical spectroscopy.

There is an active and growing amateur astronomical community that can coach you.  See the Yahoo forums like http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/staranalyser/?yguid=446659582.

You need not spend much a lot of money to get exciting results.

For a good introduction see this topic, see the video interview made recently at NEAF:

http://www.skyandtelescope.com/skytel/beyondthepage/121557614.html.

Also see the August 2011 issue of *Sky & Telescope Magazine* for an article on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

There's ready made equipment already out there, such as SBIG's [Deep Space Spectrograph](http://www.sbig.com/dss7/dss7.htm) and [Self-Guiding Spectrograph](http://www.sbig.com/sbwhtmls/spectrometer2.htm). Excluding the cost of a telescope you're looking at $3-4k to get into spectroscopy, though you can go cheaper if you buy a used CCD imager or if you DIY the spectrometer.

As far as resources, you're pretty much wading into deep water on this. Sky & Telescope had an [article](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/resources/proamcollab/3307266.html?page=1&c=y) by a devoted amateur spectroscopist which has some useful tips. Additionally, there is a community of [Amateur Astronomical Spectroscopy](http://www.amateurspectroscopy.com/) enthusiasts.

Comment: See my answer below. While Wedge is correct that it can cost more than three thousand dollars to get into high resolution spectroscopy, a $190 Star Analsyer grating and some software is all the you need (other than a camera - even a DSLR will work!). See my answer below for additional links.